# NullPointerException al settear un texto en un TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Al intentar settear un texto en un TextView de la siguiente forma:

Clase -> `FavouritePet.java`

```
public class FavouritePet extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Pet> pets;
    private RecyclerView rvPets2;
    private TextView numeroLikes, nombreMascota;
    private ImageView foto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favourite_pet);

        //Establecemos la Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myActionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Para el boton de back
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        rvPets2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvPets2);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rvPets2.setLayoutManager(llm);
        inicializarAdaptador();

        pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        ordenarMascotas(pets);

        //Bundle
        Bundle bndl = getIntent().getExtras();
        Pet pet = inicializarMascotas(bndl);
        String nombreMascota = pet.getPetName();
        int numeroLikes = pet.getNumberOfLikes();
        int foto = pet.getFoto();

        this.nombreMascota = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPetNameFavourite);
        this.numeroLikes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLikesNumberFavourite);
        this.foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFavouritePetImage);

        //NullPointerException -> Estoy tratando de settear un texto en un objeto nulo.
        this.nombreMascota.setText(nombreMascota);
        this.numeroLikes.setText(numeroLikes);
        this.foto.setImageResource(foto);
    }

    public ArrayList<Pet> ordenarMascotas(ArrayList<Pet> pets) {
        Collections.sort(pets, new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o, Object t1) {
                return 0;
            }

            public int compare(Pet p1, Pet p2) {
                return new Integer(p2.getNumberOfLikes()).compareTo(new Integer(p1.getNumberOfLikes()));
            }
        });

        return pets;
    }

    public Pet inicializarMascotas(Bundle bndl) {
        String nombreMascota = bndl.getString(String.valueOf(R.string.nombre_mascota));
        int numeroLikes = bndl.getInt(String.valueOf(R.string.numberOfLikes));
        int foto = bndl.getInt(String.valueOf(R.string.foto));
        Pet p1 = new Pet (numeroLikes,nombreMascota,foto);
        pets.add(p1);

        return p1;
    }

    public void inicializarAdaptador() {
        FavouriteAdapter fva = new FavouriteAdapter(pets,this);
        rvPets2.setAdapter(fva);
    }
}
```

Los identificadores están correctamente escritos en xml.

Layout -> `cardview_favourite_pets.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardCornerRadius"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/myActionBar"
            layout="@layout/actionbar"
            >
        </include>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFavouritePetImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_left1"
            android:src="@drawable/perro"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivEmptyBoneFavourite"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dog_bone_48"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left3"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPetNameFavourite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left1"
                android:text="@string/nombre_mascota"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLikesNumberFavourite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/numberOfLikes"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFullBoneFavourite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dog_bone_48_1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left3"
                />
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Creo que el error se debe dar en algún lugar del xml porque al código Java no le veo ningún error. Buscando en el código xml, me dí cuenta que en `android:context` tenía asignado el Layout `.MainActivity`, cuando en realidad debía asignar el layout correspondiente, en mi caso `.FavouritePet` (cosas del Copy-paste jeje). Dejo el código xml a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

Layout -> `favourite_pet.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="es.uclm.mylittlepets.FavouritePet">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPets2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
08-22 09:10:52.142 2716-2716/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 2716
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.uclm.mylittlepets/es.uclm.mylittlepets.FavouritePet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.FavouritePet.onCreate(FavouritePet.java:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

EDITO:
[Aquí](http://pastebin.com/RTsjSatE) dejo el resultado del debugging al método `inicializarMascotas(bndl)`

La clase Pet es:

```
public class Pet {
    //Atributos
    private int  numberOfLikes, foto;
    private String petName;

    //Constructor
    public Pet (int numberOfLines, String petName, int foto) {
        this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLines;
        this.petName = petName;
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public int getNumberOfLikes() {
        return numberOfLikes;
    }

    public void setNumberOfLikes(int numberOfLines) {
        this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLines;
    }

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }

    public int getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto (int foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }
```

Creo que no hay ningún problema al ejecutar el método `getPetName()`

Añado la clase del adaptador -> `FavouriteAdapter.java`

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteAdapter.FavouriteViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Pet> pets;
    Activity activity;

    public FavouriteAdapter(ArrayList<Pet> pets, Activity activity){
        this.pets = pets;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public FavouriteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_favourite_pets,parent,false);

        return new FavouriteViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FavouriteViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pet pet = pets.get(position);
        asignarAtributos(holder,pet);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pets.size();
    }

    public void asignarAtributos(FavouriteViewHolder holder, Pet pet){
        holder.petName.setText(pet.getPetName());
        holder.numberOfLikes.setText(String.valueOf(pet.getNumberOfLikes()));
        holder.ibStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_48);
        holder.ivCardview.setImageResource(pet.getFoto());
        holder.ivFullBone.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_bone_48_1);
        holder.ivEmptyBone.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_bone_48);
    }

    public static class FavouriteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Atributos
        private TextView numberOfLikes, petName;
        private ImageButton ibStar;
        private ImageView ivCardview, ivFullBone, ivEmptyBone;

        public FavouriteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            asociarElementos(itemView);
        }

        public void asociarElementos(View itemView) {
            numberOfLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikesNumberFavourite);
            petName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPetNameFavourite);
            ibStar = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibStar);
            ivCardview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFavouritePetImage);
            ivFullBone = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFullBoneFavourite);
            ivEmptyBone = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEmptyBoneFavourite);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pasa que `pet.getPetName()` es null.... tienes el problema en el metodo `inicializarMascotas(bndl)` que no muestras

Comment: Ya está añadido el método

Comment: el codigo que muestras parece correcto, simplemente debuga `inicializarMascotas` y veras donde está el error. O bien el problema es con el bundle porque viene vacio o con datos incorrectos o con algun nombre de las variables que usas, como `R.string.nombre_mascota`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RTsjSatE aquí está lo que sale al debuggear

Comment: puedes editar la pregunta para añadir informacion, asi es mas claro, en cuanto a los datos, parecen correctos, no puede ser que `pet.getPetName()` no sea el metodo que te devuelve el atributo `nombreMascota` o que no lo haga bien? debuga esa parte...

Comment: ¿Te has fijado si  this.numeroLikes.setText(numeroLikes); también da nullPointerExcpetion??

Comment: Efectivamente, también me tira la excepción con `this.numeroLikes.setText(numeroLikes);`

Comment: Pues entonces claramente no está cogiendo bien el xml, puedes poner el código completo?

Comment: Nueva edición con el código xml completo

Comment: Sorry, me refiero al código donde se encuentra  this.numeroLikes.setText(numeroLikes);

Comment: Nueva edición con la clase de java al completo

Comment: Te puse una respuesta, avísame si necesita mas ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mirando bien el código veo que el xml de la actividad es el siguiente :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="es.uclm.mylittlepets.FavouritePet">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPets2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Y tu estás intentado llamar a elementos que se encuentran en otro xml el cual se llama `cardview_favourite_pets.xml`, no se si estás intentado rellenar el recyclerView `rvPets2`, pero si es así debes llamar a

```
private TextView numeroLikes, nombreMascota;
private ImageView foto;
```

dentro del adaptador `FavouriteAdapter fva = new FavouriteAdapter(pets,this);` y asignarles valores en el mismo.

Comment: Exacto, lo que intento hacer es rellenar el recyclerView. ¿No lo estoy haciendo bien entonces? ¿Cómo dices que debería hacerlo? En el método onBindViewHolder del adaptador?

Comment: si en el método onBindViewHolder pero si puedes poner el código del adaptador te lo muestro

Comment: Está actualizado de nuevo

Comment: Okey lo tienes bien el adaptador, con eliminar las lineas donde llamas a esos elementos en la actividad sería suficiente

Answer (score 0):

Intenta substituir esto en tu primera parte:

```
Pet pet = inicializarMascotas(bndl);
String nombrePet = pet.getPetName();
TextView nombreMascota;
int numeroLikes = pet.getNumberOfLikes();
int foto = pet.getFoto();

this.nombreMascota = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPetNameFavourite);
this.numeroLikes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLikesNumberFavourite);
this.foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFavouritePetImage);

this.nombreMascota.setText(nombrePet); //-> NullPointerException
this.numeroLikes.setText(numeroLikes);
this.foto.setImageResource(foto);
```

Comment: es verdad que se oculta el atributo de clase, pero aqui no causa problema ya que `this` está usado correctamente

Comment: Creo que ahí no está el problema compañero